# How to make a contour shading like this

Tags: plotting, graphics

How can I adjust the contour shading to appear like below?

[image]

Comment: You should also look into [`DensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
 ContourPlot[Cos[x - y] + Sin[x^2 + 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome",ContourStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity@.1]]
```

[image]

You can also use `ColorFunction -> ColorData["GrayTones"]` for gray shades or even write your own following the [reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html).